# docker build image name is <none> with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I specify in Dockerfile `FROM ubuntu:jammy` but the image built is `<none>`. It does not appear to be dangling. I am following a tutorial and can't see the reason why the name is `<none>` instead of `ubuntu:jammy`. I'm on Windows 11 WSL.

```
sergio@Home-Win11:/mnt/Linkedin-Docker-Essential-Training/04_03_before$ cat Dockerfile
#my first dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:jammy
sergio@Home-Win11:/mnt/c/Linkedin-Docker-Essential-Training/04_03_before$ docker image build .
[+] Building 1.0s (5/5) FINISHED                          docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 76B                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:jammy     0.8s
 => CACHED [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:jammy@sha256:aabed3  0.0s
 => exporting to image                                              0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                             0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:18f1928b30e0cc26fd9e768656be0c61f3fc5e  0.0s
sergio@Home-Win11:/mnt/c/Linkedin-Docker-Essential-Training/04_03_before$ docker image list
REPOSITORY               TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
redis                    latest    da63666bbe9a   7 days ago     138MB
nginx                    latest    61395b4c586d   7 days ago     187MB
portainer/portainer-ce   latest    d7f7a88e1acc   8 days ago     294MB
<none>                   <none>    18f1928b30e0   6 weeks ago    77.8MB
hello-world              latest    9c7a54a9a43c   4 months ago   13.3kB
sergio@Home-Win11:/mnt/c/Linkedin-Docker-Essential-Training/04_03_before$ docker images -a
REPOSITORY               TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
redis                    latest    da63666bbe9a   7 days ago     138MB
nginx                    latest    61395b4c586d   7 days ago     187MB
portainer/portainer-ce   latest    d7f7a88e1acc   8 days ago     294MB
<none>                   <none>    18f1928b30e0   6 weeks ago    77.8MB
hello-world              latest    9c7a54a9a43c   4 months ago   13.3kB
```

Comment: The name isn't `ubuntu:jammy` because that's a _different_ image, the base image. If you want _your_ image to have a name/tag, specify them in the build.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe , linkedin course has this wrong then because only $docker image build . and Dockerfile is FROM unbutu. Hence produces <None>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour when:

- not specifying a tag: `docker build .`

```
REPOSITORY  TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED  SIZE
<none>      <none>   0ce4e70c517d   now      77.8MB
```

- specifying a repository: `docker build -t mytag .`

```
REPOSITORY  TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED  SIZE
mytag       latest   0ce4e70c517d   now      77.8MB
```

- specifying a repository and tag: `docker build -t mytag:1.0 .`

```
REPOSITORY  TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED  SIZE
mytag       1.0      0ce4e70c517d   now      77.8MB
```

Answer (score -3):

This worked

```
sergio@Home-Win11:/mnt/c/Linkedin-Docker-Essential-Training/04_03_before$ docker image build . -t myubuntu
[+] Building 1.0s (5/5) FINISHED                          docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 70B                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest    0.9s
 => CACHED [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu@sha256:aabed3296a3d  0.0s
 => exporting to image                                              0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                             0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:18f1928b30e0cc26fd9e768656be0c61f3fc5e  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/myubuntu                         0.0s
sergio@Home-Win11:/mnt/c/Linkedin-Docker-Essential-Training/04_03_before$ docker image list
REPOSITORY               TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
redis                    latest    da63666bbe9a   7 days ago     138MB
nginx                    latest    61395b4c586d   7 days ago     187MB
portainer/portainer-ce   latest    d7f7a88e1acc   8 days ago     294MB
myubuntu                 latest    18f1928b30e0   6 weeks ago    77.8MB
hello-world              latest    9c7a54a9a43c   4 months ago   13.3kB
sergio@Home-Win11:/mnt/c/Linkedin-Docker-Essential-Training/04_03_before$ cat Dockerfile
#my first dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
```

Comment: What is "this"? What have you changed to resolve the problem?

Comment: Hey @NicoHaase it's on the prompts shown. dockerfile now says FROM ubuntu instead of ubuntu:jammy. And now I specify the name to build the image docker image build . -t myubuntu

Comment: Changing the FROM is irrelevant. The repository/tag is what's needed (and in all the docker documentation)